# Is the sentence "all apples are red" an atomic sentence?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

In *An Introduction to Logic* by Patrick Suppes, an atomic sentence is defined as a sentence that contains no sentential connective. However, in a later chapter, a sentence is defined as a formula which contains no free variables.

Now if we take a sentence like *all apples are red*, it could be symbolized as (x)( A(x) => R(x) ) which does contain an implication. So is that sentence an atomic sentence or not?

Answer (score 8):

In propositional logic *sentence* and *formula* are synonyms.

An *atomic* sentence is a formula without propositional connectives [see Suppes, page 12].

In predicate logic, *sentence* and *formula* have different meaning: a *sentence* is a formula with no occurrences of *free* variables [see Def. page 54].

The formal definition of *formula* for predicate logic is at page 52:

> a *predicate* followed by the appropriate number of *terms* as arguments is an *atomic formula* [examples: **Px,Rxy**].

Formulas are: atomic formula or formulas produced using connectives and quantifiers.

Thus, "Socrates is a philosopher", which can be symbolized with **Phil(S)**, is an example of atomic sentence, while "Every Greek is a philosoper" [ **∀x ( Greek(x) → Phil(x))** ] is not.